# Clean Windows 7 Install, Put System Reserved Partition on 2nd drive

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, installation

I have done a clean install of windows on a machine with two fresh disks. By default, it put the System Reserved Partition (~100mb) on the machine's 2nd drive.

I don't want this, as I don't want to have to clone 2 disks to ensure that my system is backed up, and I intended to use the separate disk for a SQL server install, so ideally I want that entire disk dedicated to that.

1. What are the benefits of this type of set up e.g. where the system partition is on a separate disk? Can I assume this default install behavior be different if I had unmounted the 2nd disk first?
2. Can I safely (and easily) move this partition without installing a bunch of extra software to handle it **and without any other negative consequences**? I don't want to do the windows install over again, as I've spend a few days installing software, etc. and I'd rather not repeat that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I handled this very easily using EasyBSD free community edition.

Launch the app, click "BCD Backup/Repair", select "Change boot drive" and click "perform action". Select the desired drive letter (in my case, C:), and click ok. Detailed step instructions here: https://neosmart.net/wiki/easybcd/basics/changing-the-boot-partition/

Next, reboot and enter bios. Remove the old disk from the boot sequence, and ensure that the new drive is included in the boot sequence in the desired order. Save changes, and reboot.